# ForgotPasswordScreen in firebase_ui_auth is revealing if account does not exist

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am following [example](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_ui_auth/example) for [firebase_ui_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ui_auth/example) , When a visitor to site enters a valid but non existing email address, the site is revealing that the EMAIL_NOT_FOUND as shown below

[image: Account doesn't exist]

We do not want to reveal if the user exist or not.

Below is what chrome sends as curl equivalent

```
curl "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendOobCode?key=AgwiSyC-tRO9CaBdWeRMU_a1234567-Jl1234ec" ^
  -H "authority: identitytoolkit.googleapis.com" ^
  -H "accept: */*" ^
  -H "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9" ^
  -H "content-type: application/json" ^
  -H "origin: http://localhost:63865" ^
  -H "sec-ch-ua: ^\^"Not_A Brand^\^";v=^\^"99^\^", ^\^"Google Chrome^\^";v=^\^"109^\^", ^\^"Chromium^\^";v=^\^"109^\^"" ^
  -H "sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0" ^
  -H "sec-ch-ua-platform: ^\^"Windows^\^"" ^
  -H "sec-fetch-dest: empty" ^
  -H "sec-fetch-mode: cors" ^
  -H "sec-fetch-site: cross-site" ^
  -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" ^
  -H "x-client-data: CInaygE=" ^
  -H "x-client-version: Chrome/JsCore/9.15.0/FirebaseCore-web" ^
  -H "x-firebase-gmpid: 1:621401234567:web:7d6e685agh2315aea7f93b" ^
  --data-raw "^{^\^"requestType^\^":^\^"PASSWORD_RESET^\^",^\^"email^\^":^\^"example1^@example.com^\^"^}" ^
  --compressed
```

and below is the response

> {   "error": {
> "code": 400,
> "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",
> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",
> "domain": "global",
> "reason": "invalid"
> }
> ]   } }

Basically there are two scenario when [Email Enumeration protection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#enumeration-protection) can help, but it does not help when to find out if the user exists in system and a person tries to register ( sign-up) with that email again at that time the app will reveal that the account does exists.

It works in other two scenario that is when password reset or an attempt is made to log on.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds correct: Firebase Authentication can only send password reset emails to accounts that it knows about. If no user was registered for the email before, it cannot send a password reset email to it.

Comment: but I do not want to tell the visitor that the user does not exist else other can simply query who is member to my site or not.

Comment: In that case you might want to [enable email enumeration protection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#enumeration-protection) that was just released a couple of months ago.

Comment: I enabled the email enumeration protection, but when I try to register an existing number it fails and reveals that the An account with this email already exists.
 though it worked fine when Forget password is used, it simply tells that an email is send.